# Is there a lite version of Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberrypi, 21.10, cluster

I'm going to build a cluster of Pis. But before I order the SD cards, I want to know if there is a lite version of Ubuntu so that I can use smaller SD cards. Raspberry Pi OS lite is a smaller OS which just has command-line interface and ssh. No extra graphics or anything.

Do I need to use Ubuntu server? Is there anything else than Lubuntu and Xubuntu? Or can I use PI OS lite for the slave nodes while the master node is running Ubuntu because they both use the Linux kernel?

Comment: Perhaps try Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi: https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi/thank-you?version=21.10&architecture=desktop-arm64+raspi, or maybe Ubuntu Mate for Raspberry Pi: https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/install/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Ubuntu Server for Raspberry Pi is a good choice. The requirement here is only 4 GB SD card (although 8 GB is recommended). I reckon the unpacked OS image is around 2,5 GB.

It's all in the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi).

Running more nodes with different OS'es is out of scope for this particular site - thus, you should edit your question to focus on Ubuntu only.

Comment: so ubuntu lite is ubuntu server, right?

Comment: Ubuntu Server is the most "lightweight" Ubuntu variant, yes.

Comment: the unpacked os is 4.1 gb